# matlab, ncdispが動かないです

Tags: matlab

matlab初心者です、授業でncdispを使って、外部のデータを取り込んで解析するということをやっております。
一度、windowsように環境変数にproxyを設定し、大学で動いていたのですが、今日久しぶりに開いたところ、読み込んでもエラーが出てしまい、原因がわかりません。
これは、大学のwifiでないからなのでしょうか？　自宅からVPNで大学のwifiに接続しているのですが、、、。

[このサイトのデータを読み込む](http://tds.hycom.org/thredds/dodsC/GLBa0.08/expt_91.2.html)

```
opdurl = 'http://tds.hycom.org/thredds/dodsC/GLBa0.08/expt_91.2';
ncdisp(opdurl);
```

たったこれだけなのですが、

```
エラー: ndap (line 3)
ncdisp(opdurl);
```

としか、出ません。
大学にいたときには、正常に動いていたのですが、なぜでしょう。原因が全くわかりません。

ご指導のほどお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/205461

Comment: おそらくネットワークの設定の問題だと思います。ラップトップを大学内のネットワークにVPN経由で接続し、そのラップトップ上でMATLABを起動しているということでいいのでしょうか。「環境変数にproxyを設定」とありますが、具体的にどのような設定をしたのでしょうか。

Comment: 大学のwifi内のもと、講義資料のいうとおりに以下の環境変数を設定しました.         変数名 http_proxy, 変数値 proxy.noc.[ 省略].   変数名 http_proxys, 変数値 proxy.noc.[ 省略].

Comment: 今の自宅では、個人のwifiを使用しており、大学の接続はしていません

Comment: 大学のvpnに接続しても、やはり動きません..

Answer (score 0):

大学内のwifiを使わないときは、環境変数で設定したproxyを削除したら動きました。